# Spring Boot java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a problem with my spring-boot application because I can't start it when I use the Jar next a maven build. But I can start it in my IDE ...

The exception is :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
```

My POM.XML

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I look in the jar file I have a folder lib/ which contains the spring-boot-start-data-jpa-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar so I don't understand why the jar can't find CrudRepository ...

Any Idea ?
Thank you very much

**EDIT**

My lib folder in jar content :

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar
classmate-1.0.0.jar
cxf-core-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-wsdl-3.0.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
guava-18.0.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar
jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar
jackson-core-2.4.6.jar
jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
jaxb-core-2.2.10-b140310.1920.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.10-b140310.1920.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
logback-core-1.1.3.jar
neethi-3.0.3.jar
ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
snakeyaml-1.14.jar
spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-aop-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-ws-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-support-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-xml-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.0.23.jar
tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.23.jar
tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar
tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar
tomcat-juli-8.0.23.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar
```

Comment: Set the jar scope to `compile`?

Comment: I've the same problem with the scope compile on spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem.

I was using Guava to find all classes annotate by @WebService and i create the bean. But all bean were not load. So I'm now using the ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider which sleep while Spring stop to create bean.

Thank for your Answer